# Jetpack Infinite Scroll not working in Front page

Tags: php, wordpress, infinite-scroll, jetpack

I am working on a theme which has post types -  'tour'.

I am using JetPack's infinite scroll to render new posts:

**function.php**

```
            function tweakjp_custom_is_support() {
                $supported = current_theme_supports( 'infinite-scroll' ) && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ||  is_archive() || is_single());

                return $supported;
            }
            add_filter( 'infinite_scroll_archive_supported', 'tweakjp_custom_is_support' ); 

            function my_child_infinite_scroll_render() {
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_type());
                endwhile;
            }

            function my_child_setup() {
                add_theme_support( 'infinite-scroll', array(
                    'type'           => 'scroll',
                    'container'      => 'mob_infinite',
                    'render'         => 'my_child_infinite_scroll_render',
                    'posts_per_page' => 2,
                ) );
            }

            add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_child_setup' );
```

**Front Page**

```
            <div class="container">
                <div id="mob_infinite">
                    $args = array ('post_type' => 'post');

                    $myquery = new wp_query($args);

                    if($myquery->have_posts() ){
                        while($myquery->have_posts() ) : $myquery->the_post();

                            get_template_part( 'content', get_post_type() );

                        endwhile;
                    } 
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what your problem is. Actual/expected behavior.

Comment: And Custom Post Type code in Front Page is:
..........

    <div class="container">
     <div id="mob_infinite">
      $args = array ('post_type' => 'tour');

      $myquery = new wp_query($args);

      if($myquery->have_posts() ){
       while($myquery->have_posts() ) : $myquery->the_post();
                
        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_type() );
        
       endwhile;
      } 
     </div>
    </div>

Comment: Check your browser console to see if there are javascript errors and report back please.

Comment: @MukeshSaini edit your question if you'd like to post any additional code.